# Symfony2 forms ignores attributes in custom fields when same defined in buidler

Tags: php, forms, symfony, custom-controls, symfony-forms

When I define attributes in form builder and same attributes as default in custom field the other are ignored. In form builder I have:

```
    $builder
            ->add('validityOfADecisionOnDisability', new JQDateType(), array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'rel' => 'permanent',
                )
            ))
```

and custom field

```
class JQDateType extends AbstractType {

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'datepicker'
        )
    );
}
```

and it renders html

```
<input type="text" rel="permanent" required="required" 
  name="profile[validityOfADecisionOnDisability]" 
  id="profile_validityOfADecisionOnDisability">
```

without class. But when I add class to attributes in builder

```
    $builder
            ->add('validityOfADecisionOnDisability', new JQDateType(), array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'rel' => 'permanent',
                    'class' => 'datepicker',
                )
            ))
```

eevrything works as expected. How should I define attributes in JQDateType() ? I tried to use array_merge() and array_merge_recursive() in JQDateType::getDefaultOptions() but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug that is fixed in Symfony 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

@Koral I guess you can use annotation in your Entity class is better than 'getDefaultOptions' ,you can see here  :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

Comment: But getDefaultOptions() is for form field and annotations are for entites

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can validate all fields of your forms directly in your Entity Class,for example :

```
/**
 * @Assert\Min(limit = "18", message = "You must be 18 or older to enter")
 */
 protected $age;
```

Comment: My question have nothing in common with validation. Field name is validityOfADecisionOnDisability.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug. You should open a ticket on https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues